# How do I stop a custom Thead in SWT application?

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, dispose

**How do I stop a custom Thread when I exit my SWT application?**

`MyThread` runs in an infinite loop, until a certain condition becomes true:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

  @Override
  public void run() {
     do {
        // Do stuff...
     }
     while (!this.isInterrupted() && otherCondition);

}
```

In my SWT application I do start the thread and try to stop in in the SWT composite's `dispose()` method. However, this method is never called.

```
class MyComposite extends Composite {

    private MyThread myThread = null;

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
      super.dispose();

      if (null != this.myThread) {
         this.myThread.interrupt();
      }
    }

    public void somewhere() {
       this.myThread = new MyThread();
       this.myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Now, it can happen that I have closed my SWT application window already, but the thread keeps running (it still creates debug output). Isn't the `dispose()` method called automatically? What is the best way to make the thread stop, if the user closes the application window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All controls are disposed when their parent window is closed, but **not** by calling their `dispose` method (an internal method called `release` is called). So as mentioned in another answer you need to use a `DisposeListener` to be informed about the dispose.

Alternatively your thread can call `setDaemon(true)` - the JVM does not wait for daemon threads to stop when closing an application.

Comment: Addendum: The method ``setDaemon()`` must be called before the thread is started.

Comment: Setting the deamon flag looks like a good solution, since it can be set within the Thread's constructor and no one has to worry about stopping the thread in SWT.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `dispose()` your widgets by yourself. I do not know how you get rid of your widgets since the snippet does not contain any code for that.

Every class that extends `Widget` allows registering  a `DisposeListener` (using `addDisposeListener()` method). As soon as a widget is disposed you'll be notified.

Btw. you've got maybe a typo, your `if` checks if `this.checker` is not null and your thread field is named `myThread`

Comment: The ``this.checker`` was my fault, indeed. Thanks, I fixed it. Plus I removed the stop flag, since I can also use ``interrupt()`` and ``isInterrupted()`` here. So there is no need to introduce another stop flag.